# Creating Toast Message without button pressed in react js

Tags: reactjs

**Hi Everyone am new to react js can anyone please guide me on how to display Toast Message without using button, i want to show error message on page load using Toast Notification can anyone help me or suggest me on how to do it

Comment: You can use libraries like [react-toastr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastr) for this purpose.

Comment: Any example you have because i find react-toastr with button and i want to display toast message on page load(without any click action)

Comment: No need of any buttons. Check this for sample code https://tomchentw.github.io/react-toastr. You can call `container.success` upon successful load like in `componentDidMount` etc..

Comment: With most libraries that have toast functionality you would call a function that will show the toast. You don't need a button to call the function, so this shouldn't be a big problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a simple, one time toast message, you could use the React Hooks API.

Some pseudocode, not considering animations and styles:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function ToastMessage({ message, duration = 2000 }) {

    const [ showToast, setShowToast ] = useState(false)

    // the empty array as the second argument
    // ensures it is fired only after component mount.

    useEffect(() => {
       setShowToast(true)

       // Hides the message after 2 default seconds (configurable)
       setTimeout(() => setShowToast(false), duration)
    }, [])

    return (
       showToast &&
          <div>{props.message}</div> || null
    )

}


// Then in your page...
// Assuming you have your error coming from somewhere in your props

function Page(props) {

    const [ hasError, setHasError ] = useState(props.error !== '')
    
    return (
       <>
         <Header />
         <PageContent />
         <Footer />
         { hasError && 
              <ToastMessage 
                  message={props.error} 
                  duration={1000} /> 
         }
       </>

    )
}
```